# php (rar) i want to rar a folder using rar on Ubuntu (linux) by php (on dedi server) noob

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-9.10, rar

hey guyz i want rar (not tar) my folder on my server by using php

RAR

> RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010
>   Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010 
>   Registered to  my real name

OS

> Ubuntu  Release  (Karmic) kernel linux
>   2.6.32.2-xxxx-grs-ipv4-32 Gnome 2.28.1

latest php an lighthttpd

i have tried these things

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php   // may be wrong code 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
```

my command  (working in ssh and nautilus script)

```
rar a -m0 /where/file/will/saved/file_name.rar /location/ti/data/dir/datafolder
```

php code

```
$log=Shell_exec("rar a -m0 /where/file/will/saved/file_name.rar /location/ti/data/dir/datafolder");
echo $log;
```

one method is left which i don't know how to use and its working on server that is by somefile_to_execute_command.sh i have to execute .sh file from php need to send some variables (command) and

i tried this method can rar file with a script named RapidLeech but its rar from only its own files dir only  :( but i want to do in different directories.

Rapid Leech rar class

```
http://paste2.org/p/791668
```

i m able run shell command with php (cp(copy),mv(move),ls(directory list),rm(remove aka delete)) but got failed to run rar i gives no output i also tried to given path rar and i used alot commands with php Shell_exec function and working like they work with ssh and i have tried almost 80 % method given on net and failed from last 3days i m over now plz help me i need php script file working plz reply if u have any info n code and experience about rar and this kinda :( problem

i m 99% noob just used code mean  search Google collect script make my own working thing (for personal use only) n now i m failed to rar folder and file :((

now plz provide me code plz don't talk in technical language because i m just reading my first php book (for dummies :D) mean noob and 0.1

plz help me as much as u can

thankx

Comment: The results of `asking for teh codez` while asking for `non technical` answers on Stack Overflow are undefined.

Comment: i can understand something but not in deep :( i m newbie :(

Comment: Maybe `rar` is not in the `PATH`; have you tried using the full path to the `rar` executable?

Comment: yes salathe  i tried :(
and also copy paste working rar to its directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rar package which comes with ubuntu. Just see `rar --help` for rar package help.
Then, just call it inside the php itself using the [system function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or the shell_exec.

Comment: i tried it but not working  

n using paid licensed rar ( winrar Downloaded from rarlab and compile it ((also downloaded working executable file) working with normal ssh connection ) rar is working normal with ssh but  not working php